# Angularjs - Reloading a route

Tags: javascript, location, angularjs, routes

Is it possible to reload a certain route if "something" happens?

**Example:**
Everytime this function is triggered, I need to reload the route with the new ID

```
$scope.updateDealer = function(zip, country) {
        if(zip) {
            $http.get('files/framework/dealer/near/'+ zip + '/' + country + '').success(function(data) {
                $scope.dealer = {marker: data};
                $location.path('/dealer/:id').search({id: data.id});
                $rootScope.dealerdetails = data;    
                $route.reload();
        });
        } else {
            $scope.dealer = $scope.loadall();
        }

  }
```

**Routes**:

```
when('/dealer/:id', {templateUrl: 'files/tpl/dealer-details.html?26', controller: 'DealerDetailsCtrl', activetab: 'details'}).
```

But somehow, the ID isn't in the DealerDetailsCtrl.

**This is the call for the data in DealerDetailsCtrl:**

```
$rootScope.dealerdetails = dealerService.api.get({id: $routeParams.id, token: $scope.token})
```

It seems that $routeParams.id is empty and therefor the content isn't loading.

Thank you for your help.

Comment: instead of `$route.reload()` wouldn't it be easier to call `window.location.href` with the appropriate parameters matching your routes?

Comment: Can you add a Plunker of jsFiddle with the problem code so we can take a look? Also, why do you need to "reload" your current route instead of just refreshing your content through bindings?

Comment: window.location.href is not possible because the content is loading in an open overlay div. The site has to be "reload" free... The "reload()" was just a try.

Answer (score 0):

If you visit /dealer/1 (or whatever the id actually is) is $routeParams.id defined for you? All you should have to do is:

```
    $scope.updateDealer = function(zip, country) {
        if(zip) {
            $http.get('files/framework/dealer/near/'+ zip + '/' + country + '').success(function(data) {
                $scope.dealer = {marker: data};
                $rootScope.dealerdetails = data;
                $location.path('/dealer/' + data.id);
            });
        } else {
            $scope.dealer = $scope.loadall();
        }
  }
```

Answer (score 0):

Since angular 1.3 you can use `$route.updateParams(newParams)` to change route params.

[Here is a quote from the angular docs...](https://code.angularjs.org/1.3.0/docs/api/ngRoute/service/$route#updateParams)

> **$route.updateParams(newParams);**
>
> Causes `$route` service to update the current URL, replacing current route parameters with those specified
>   in `newParams`. Provided property names that match the route's path
>   segment definitions will be interpolated into the location's path,
>   while remaining properties will be treated as query params.

In your case you should use something like this:

```
$scope.updateDealer = function(zip, country) {
     if(zip) {
         $http.get('files/framework/dealer/near/'+ zip + '/' + country + '').success(function(data) {
             $scope.dealer = {marker: data};    
             $route.updateParams({id: data.id});
         });
     } else {
         $scope.dealer = $scope.loadall();
     }
}
```

Comment: Please note however, as soon as the route params are updated, the current `DealerDetailsCtrl` controller and scope will be destroyed and re instantiated. So, if `$scope.updateDealer` is defined in the `DealerDetailsCtrl` (which I couldn't figure out from your question) `$scope.dealer` will get lost. You might have to save it to a higher scope or use a service.

Answer (score -1):

This should do the trick since Angular monitors hash changes routes them appropriately:

```
window.location.hash = 'dealer/data.id';
```

Comment: please provide an answer!